# How to use linux command in python with python functions (sys.argv)

Tags: python, bash

In my python script, I need to use 'awk' but I want to pass file using the sys.argv.
My current code is like this:

```
import sys
import os

cmd="awk '/regex/ {print}' sys.argv[1] | sed 's/old/new/g'"
x=os.popen(cmd).read()
```

Now the problem is that 'sys.argv' is a python thing but cmd variable is using a linux command.
So my question is - Is there any way to include sys.argv in my linux command?

Comment: If you are already programming in Python, are you sure you need to call awk? Python probably can do everything you need from awk just fine.

Comment: Just wrap it in quotes: `python somefile.py 'some commands here'`

Comment: Simply use string formatting:
`cmd=f"awk '/regex/ {{print}}' %s | sed 's/old/new/g'" % (sys.argv[1])`

Comment: @C.Nivs Actually the code I posted is a part of a big script. I cannot directly use commands from outside like that.

Comment: @nibba I think I misread your question. Are you trying to pass a linux command to python as a string? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: cmd="awk '/regex/ {print}' %s | sed 's/old/new/g'" % sys.argv[1]

Comment: You don't need `sed`:  `cmd="awk '/regex/{gsub(/old/,\"new\");print}' %s" % sys.argv[1] `

Comment: @JasonMorgan, from a security perspective that's a horrid idea. What if `sys.argv[1]` contains `$(rm -rf ~)`? Or even `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, so you can't escape it with literal single quotes?

Comment: @Charles Duffy, the OP asked how to put the sys.argv into the cmd, they did not ask how to do it safely.  IMO the question is flawed as it's the wrong way to go about things from the outset.  The OP does not say what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JasonMorgan, teaching known-unsafe practices *makes the world a worse place*. I mean, as someone building malware-analysis products, prevalence of open attack surface helps make sure there's a market, but if I could flip a switch and make my field obsolete, I'd be happy to be looking for different work.

Comment: @JasonMorgan Thanks that was so easy and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need Awk or `sed` for this. Python can do these things natively, elegantly, flexibly, robustly, and naturally.

```py
import sys
import re

r = re.compile(r'regex')
s = re.compile(r'old')

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input:
    for line in input:
        if r.search(line):
            print(s.sub('new', line))
```

If you really genuinely want to use subprocesses for something, simply use Python's general string interpolation functions where you need to insert the value of a Python variable into a string.

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex

result = subprocess.run(
    """awk '/regex/ {print}' {} | 
    sed 's/old/new/g'""".format(shlex.quote(sys.argv[1])),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True, check=True)
print(subprocess.stdout)
```

But really, don't do this. If you really can't avoid a subprocess, keep it as simple as possible (avoid `shell=True` and peel off all the parts which can be done in Python).

Comment: Your section approach using `format()` has security vulnerabilities as currently formulated. Please either use `shlex.quote()`/`pipes.quote()`, or (better) pass a list to `subprocess.run()` and pass the value out-of-band from the code (as in this usage mode with `shell=True`, only the first list element is parsed as code; the second becomes `$0`, the third `$1`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, adding `shlex.quote()` as an easy fix. Rearranging the pipeline so as to avoid `shell=True` is cumbersome, though there is some limited support via the Python `pipes` module.

Comment: Another easy workaround would be to pass an open file handle from Python ; `with open(sys.argv[1]) as input: subprocess.run(..., stdin=input)`

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this

```
cmd="awk '/regex/ {print}' " + str(sys.argv[1]) + " | sed 's/old/new/g'"
x=os.popen(cmd).read()
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is already a string, you don't need to use `str()`.

Comment: From a security perspective this is horrible. Think about what happens if `./yourpythonprog '$(rm -rf ~)'` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice is to implement your logic as pure Python logic, as described in the first part of [the answer by @tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742522/14122). Your second best choice is to keep the external tools, but eliminate the need for a shell in invoking them and connecting them together.

See the Python documentation section [Replacing Shell Pipelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(['awk', '/regex/ {print}'], stdin=open(sys.argv[1]), stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['sed', 's/old/new/g'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
x = p2.communicate()[0]
```

---

Your *third* best choice is to keep the shell, but pass the data out-of-band from the code:

```
p = subprocess.run([
  """awk '/regex/ {print}' <"$1" | sed 's/old/new/'""",  # code to run
  '_',                                                   # $0 in context of that code
  sys.argv[1]                                            # $1 in context of that code
], shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout)
```